# Second cohomology of surface with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary, non-orientable-surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a connected surface with boundary. If $\Sigma$ is compact and orientable, then Lefschetz duality implies that $H^2(\Sigma;\Bbb Z)\cong H_0(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma;\Bbb Z)=0$. Can we compute the second cohomology of $\Sigma$ without compactness or orientability assumptions?

Comment: $H^2(\Sigma;\Bbb Z)=0$ if $\Sigma$ is non-compact or non-orientable or with boundary. $H^2_c(\Sigma;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z$ if $\Sigma$ is non-compact orientable without boundary. $H^2_c(\Sigma;\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$ if $\Sigma$ is non-compact without boundary, may or may-not be orientable. $H^2_c(\Sigma, \partial \Sigma;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z$ if $\Sigma$ is non-compact orientable with boundary. $H^2_c(\Sigma, \partial \Sigma;\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$ if $\Sigma$ is non-compact with boundary, may or may-not be orientable.

Comment: I assumed $\Sigma$ to be connected surface and second-countable. $c$ denotes the compactly supported cohomology. So, you have to consider $\Bbb Z_2$-coefficients for non-orientable surface; relative cohomology w.r.t. $\partial \Sigma$ for surface with non-empty boundary; and compactly supported cohomology for non-compact surface to obtain non-zero top (ordinary/generalized) cohomology.